# Issues with Video tag in HTML

Tags: html, css, web

I have a couple of videos on a webpage that I am making and there is a fixed div above them, when I scroll down on the page the control bar of the video tag is visible through the fixed div.`<video width="560 height="315" controls="true">
<source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>`

And here is the fixed div css

```
.info {
background-image: url('http://bluewallpaperbackground.weebly.com/uploads/1/9/7/6/19768865/8686693_orig.jpg');
width: 100%;
height: 37%;
border-bottom: 2px solid white;
padding: 10px;
position: fixed;
}
```

[The play bar is visible through the fixed div, which is the brick with the text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZ42h.jpg)

Comment: Are you using `opacity: ...` somewhere?

Comment: Nope, no opacity anywhere

Comment: Do you have a link to the page that I could check out or an image?

Comment: I have added a link to an image

Comment: Could you add the CSS for the video and everything in it?

Comment: There is no css for the video other than a border, I experimented with some stuff to try to make the control bar disappear but nothing that I know worked.

Comment: Where are you wanting that control? Should it be under the fixed div? (I feel like the problem isn't with your fixed div...)

Comment: I want to controls under the fixed div, yeah.

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the fixed div to have a z-index of 999.

```
.info {
z-index: 999 ;
}
```

The z-index property specifies the stack order of an element. An element with greater stack order is always in front of an element with a lower stack order.

Comment: Problem Solved, Thanks a ton!

Comment: The z-index property specifies the stack order of an element. An element with greater stack order is always in front of an element with a lower stack order.